# Shortcut key to adjust brightness in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to allocate a shortcut key for adjusting the screen brightness in windows PC?
Example: I press Alt+B and it call some script or bat file to adjust screen brightness.

Answer (score 2):

I offer you three options:

1. Open quick setting window throw `Win + X` and change brigtness there
2. Make two power plans with different brightness setting; change
   between them in the taskbar (battery icon)
3. Try one of that: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-dim-or-increase-the-brightness-of-laptop-or-notebook-lcd-screen/

I use the second option for years